# Remove / delete all items in listview checkbox selected

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Is there a small example to show how a table in the listview where there are functions to remove all selected items on the checkbox?

Please help me, thanks!

Comment: Using an active View in a ListView can cause problem, Views get recycled in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom adapter concept then you can maintain flag value for each row with your details of each row. Initially flag will be false and wheneveryou check/click on any row make that flag of that row to true. and in get view method or on any click event you can check  and remove the all the selected items from the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing code, I'll answer with concept.

On the event of deleting all the items checked, you have to get the position of these checked items and remove them from the array you passed to the adapter (whatever adapter you used), then use the function `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();` and they will be removed from the list.